# Facebook sharing in Libgdx

Tags: java, android, facebook, libgdx

I followed the facebook tutorial on [sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share) a link.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

and use this interface for share button inside the game

```
    @Override
    public void fbShare() {

    if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), 
    FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
    // Publish the post using the Share Dialog
    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
    .setLink("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viralsoft.RocketBoost")
    .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

    } else {
    // Fallback. For example, publish the post using the Feed Dialog
    }
    }
```

When I push the share button facebook shows, the link is there and I can also write something but when I push share it is not posting on my wall.  What code am I missing? And I also want to share the game's highscore.  I'm just beginning to learn in java programming the facebook sdk tutorial is not that comprehensive to me.  Thanks!